# What is offline data saving limit of Firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Firebase Database gives 10 MB of offline database cache limit as per their documentation but there is no mentioning of offline data limit for **Firestore** database.

What is offline data saving limit of Firestore ?

Answer (score 6):

As per Firebase Support Team Answer

-
As of the moment, there is no limit on the size of the cached data for **Firestore**, however, this lack of limit is a known issue.
We intend to implement this on Firestore, though we cannot provide any timeline on when will this be released.

So for now there is no limit of offline storage for **Firestore**

Support ticket response in mail have attached a link of its screenshot here please check - photos.app.goo.gl/bynk314vrnxF0Odk2

Comment: Can we have the link to this support ticket?

Comment: i dont know exactly where can i find the link of support ticket, but i got the support ticket response in my mail and have attached a link of its screenshot, please check - https://photos.app.goo.gl/bynk314vrnxF0Odk2

Answer (score 0):

The limit is configurable from a minimum of 1MB to unlimited.

Here's the [link to the official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#configure_cache_size).